# Subclass of UITabBarController, replaced the TabBar and have a display issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iPhone app which was built using a standard UITabBarController.  This app was created using the standard XCode project template.

Now, I have a requirement to change the UITabBar to look very different.  The approach I decided to take was like this:

in my AppDelegate:

```
for (UIView *view in tabBarController.view.subviews) {  
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]]) {
        view.hidden = YES;
        break;
    }
}
```

This works to make the tab bar hidden.  Next, I subclassed `UITabBarController` and I add a `UIToolbar` with a few custom components.  In my subclassed `UITabBarController` I have my code set up so that when one of my custom objects is selected, the code simply calls `[self setSelectedIndex:n]` to update the UI.

So I basically have a UITabBarController but I am controlling it through a new UI.

The problem is that my new components aren't quite as tall as the normal `UITabBar` and the UITabBarController seems to be not resizing my views automatically.  I actually would expect this behavior, but I can't figure out how to change the "content frame" of a UITabBarController.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can try "tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES", it's a lot easier.

Comment: Note that in the UITabBarController class documentation from Apple it states: "This class is not intended for subclassing."

Comment: Subclassing is required if you want to make the tabbarcontroller rotatable though. By default, it does not pass rotation events down to its child controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with the following code:

```
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 436)];
```

(I know this code has issues btw and will come back to haunt me on the iPad or other devices).

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the autoresizingMask property.
2. Are you expecting them to work as tab bars usually do by adding items to the viewControllers view?

Comment: I'm not expecting them to work as tab bars only because I've added them to the viewController views.  I want them to display, but I know I'll have to write the code to make it functional.