# Hiding UITabBar when displaying UIPickerView in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview, uitabbar

I've got a view when I want to use UIPickerView but my application supports also UITabBar. I want to display UIPickerView in the same spot where keyboard pops up but the problem is that when I do that tab bar buttons are above picker and only half of it is beign displayed. Is is possible to temporary disable tab bar before I draw a picker and restore it when picker will disappear?

Comment: How are you displaying the UIPickerView is it through a pushModal or?

Comment: I'm adding a UIPickerView as a subview.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you show us how you're displaying the `UIPickerView`? I'll assume you're adding it as a subview to a view controller that is shown from a tab bar, and setting its frame so that it is positioned the same as the keyboard.

In that case, try adding the `UIPickerView` as a subview to the window, rather than the view controller's view:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myPickerView];
```

This should show it above all other views.

One likely caveat is that if a keyboard needs to be shown at any time while your pickerview is in place, the keyboard will show above your pickerview, hiding it until the keyboard is dismissed again.

Comment: Yes, I'm adding UIPickerView as a subview to the windows. I'll try your solution.

Answer (score 2):

What if you called

`myTabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;`

before showing this picker view?

Comment: How do I get `myTabBarController` in my custom view when it's defined in MainWindow nib?

Comment: from your controller, it's self.tabBarController.tabBar; see http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/tabBarController

Comment: This hids the tabbar but it leaves an empty white rectangle in its place.

Comment: Check out my question from 2 weeks ago:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078507/subclass-of-uitabbarcontroller-replaced-the-tabbar-and-have-a-display-issue